# android:navigationBarDividerColor requires API level 28

Tags: android, xml, android-navigation-bar

Previously, I implemented light and dark navigation bar, however now tags as `android:navigationBarDividerColor` and `android:windowLightNavigationBar` require API level 28 when they previously required API level 27.

It seems API level 28 does not even exist as next API level is called P.

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: it seems to work now on API 27 with latest support libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "next upcoming API" is **still under development**, its "name" is a letter (P in your case).
Once the **final version of the API** is available, the "name" is changed form a letter to a number (P to 28).

Final version of Android API 28 (former Android P) is [available since early June 2018](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/android-p-beta-2-and-final-apis.html).
 Just use the SDK manager and you'll be able to download it ;-)

*Note:*
Sources for "Android SDK Platform xx" (28 in your case)" is not available right away. (not available ATTOW)
It can takes a few weeks before they are available for download from the SDK manager.

Comment: But I already implemented it previously on API 27 and now it suddenly requires API 28 while it wasn't even released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've updated `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`from **27** to **28**. Now I'm facing the same issue as @Teďourek described.
While it was working for me on 27, since the upgrade I now get lint errors:

```
Error: android:navigationBarDividerColor requires API level 28 (current min is 19)
Error: windowLightNavigationBar requires API level 28 (current min is 19)
```

This is strange because according to the docs for both attributes it says:
`"added in API Level 27"`

My temporary fix is to move the two style attributes to `v28/styles.xml` instead of `v27/styles.xml`

Since I would like to use lightNavBar + color also on Android 8.1.0 as previously, I would be happy if anyone knows a fix!

Answer (score 0):

With `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set to 29 it seems to be correct.
The XML properties tell me it was added in API level 27.
Only the Java `Window` properties are added in API level 28.